# Azure Storage Queue monitoring

Tags: azure-application-insights, azure-monitoring, azure-storage-queues

Can someone help me finding correct application insight query to get Azure Storage Queue No of messages  for particular interval .

Comment: If in case you are considering an out of the box seamless solution to monitor your storage account queue, I would recommend trying out Serverless360! You will not require any queries to be defined as everything comes handy with GUI.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK you should use Azure Service Bus if you want to monitor queue lengths. Check out this article https://brettmckenzie.net/2019/10/20/consider-using-service-bus-queues-instead-of-azure-storage-queues-when-using-application-insights/